# How to install Azul JDK 16 on Apple Silicon M1 Mac?

Tags: java, macos, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I understand I can run Java under emulation with Rosetta 2, but I've read that with Azul Open JDK 16 that I can get native performance.

I downloaded the file, but have no idea what to do. Azul's help page is not helpful.

If someone can give some basic steps on how to get the JDK running natively that would be awesome!

Comment: Provide link to your download page. I do not see that Azul has yet delivered their Apple Silicon port.

Comment: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk

Answer (score 4):

[Azul actually just updated](https://www.azul.com/press_release/azul-announces-support-of-java-builds-of-openjdk-for-apple-silicon) their downloads page and a .dmg can be found which successfully installs earlier lts versions of Java. This page can be found here:

https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk